# AWS EC2 instance Network in is occasionally very high

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running more than 10 EC2 instances on AWS

lately, i noticed that my EC2 instances network in and cpu utilizations are occasionally very high.

I don't run any snapshots, cron jobs or scripts that might effect this. even it happens for instances i created and left them as init status

Anyone knows why it happens ?

this is maximum network in for the last two weeks
[image]

Comment: Network out or network in?  Review your syslogs.  Instances have pre-configured cron jobs to do housekeeping tasks like log rotation and checking updates.

Comment: And the frequency of these spikes. If consistent interval, high possibility these are from house keeping jobs.